# Track who has opened the SharePoint List Item Attachment

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, list-item, item-attachment

I have a scenario where I need to capture who has viewed the SharePoint List item attachemnt?

I have one OOTB list form, in which a user creates an entry and also uploads the attachment(s).

I need to send an email notification when any user tries to open the attachment attached with the list item.

Do we have any kind of action/trigger in Power Automate which supports this scenario?

Open to other suggestions as well.

P.S. List is under SharePoint Online Communication Site.